# Регулярные выражения. Квантификаторы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Если мне нужно отыскать шаблон, в котором от 3 до 6 символов, я сделаю это так: `[a-z]{3,6}`, но мне нужно отыскать шаблон, в котором либо 3 символа, либо 6. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо 3, либо 6:

```
[a-z]{6}|[a-z]{3}
```

Для проверки: https://regex101.com/r/2tPQkA/1

Comment: Спасибо. Да уж, нужно было подумать чуть больше, чем 2 минуты, оказалось всё намного проще

Comment: @NaClnik, пожалуйста :) Причем лучше сначала на 6 проверить, после на 3, чтобы те, что на 3 не стриггерились. Еще можно добавить `\b` для границ

Comment: Эхх, к сожалению, не понадобилось((. Пишу парсер на antlr, а там как раз эти скобочные квантификаторы не поддерживаются

Answer (score 3):

Например так: `([a-z]{3}){1,2}`

Или так: `[a-z]{3}([a-z]{3})?`